# Access params with wildcard in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post, parameters

At the moment I have a form_tag which contains inputs and puts these inputs into parameters. 
I want to be able to loop over them in the controller action.

I've tried getting all `params` excluding all the usual `params` (action, controller, model name etc.) and then using a wildcard like `params[:prop*]`.

Here is the offending form inputs:

```
%input{:name => "userEmails", :id =>"userEmails", :type => "hidden", :value => ""}
  -@all_properties.each do |prop|
    %input{:name => "prop"+prop.name+"checkbox", :type => "checkbox", :id => "prop"+prop.name+"checkbox"}
    #{prop.name}
    %input{:name => "prop"+prop.name, :type => "text", :id => "prop"+prop.name}
```

These show up in params like `{"propProperty1checkbox"=>"on", "propProperty1" => "testing", "propAnotherPropertycheckbox" => "on", "propAnotherProperty" => "another test value"}` etc.

I'm unsure how to access these as the names of the properties can change and so need to be accessed abstractly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#select` on `params` hash to filter only the params that are interesting for you:

```
params = {"user_id"=>1, 
 "propProperty1checkbox"=>"on",                                                                                   
 "propProperty1"=>"testing",                                                                                      
 "propAnotherPropertycheckbox"=>"on",                                                                             
 "propAnotherProperty"=>"another test value"
}
params.to_h.select{|key, value| key =~ /^prop/}
#=> {"propProperty1checkbox"=>"on",
#"propProperty1"=>"testing",
#"propAnotherPropertycheckbox"=>"on",
#"propAnotherProperty"=>"another test value"}
```

**EDIT**

Example from the comment:

```
[13] pry(main)> {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxx", "userEmails"=>"teste@test.com,test2@test.com,test4@test.com,fasd@gmail.com", "propProperty1checkbox"=>"on", "propProperty1"=>"3", "propAnotherPropertycheckbox"=>"on", "propAnotherProperty"=>"4", "commit"=>"Submit", "Application"=>"8", "Company"=>"1" }.to_h.select{|k, v| k =~ /^prop/}
=> {"propProperty1checkbox"=>"on",
 "propProperty1"=>"3",
 "propAnotherPropertycheckbox"=>"on",
 "propAnotherProperty"=>"4"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me. Running `params.to_h.select{|key, value| key =~ /^prop/}` returns nothings

Comment: could you post the content of `params`?

Comment: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxx",
 "userEmails"=>"teste@test.com,test2@test.com,test4@test.com,fasd@gmail.com",
 "propProperty1checkbox"=>"on",
 "propProperty1"=>"3",
 "propAnotherPropertycheckbox"=>"on",
 "propAnotherProperty"=>"4",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "Application"=>"8",
 "Company"=>"1"
}`

Comment: This is interesting. I agree that it works when running it all at once `{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxx", "userEmails"=>"teste@test.com,test2@test.com,test4@test.com,fasd@gmail.com", "propProperty1checkbox"=>"on", "propProperty1"=>"3", "propAnotherPropertycheckbox"=>"on", "propAnotherProperty"=>"4", "commit"=>"Submit", "Application"=>"8", "Company"=>"1" }.to_h.select{|k, v| k =~ /^prop/}`

However it seems when trying to run it straight from params it does not work for some reason

Comment: Try with `{|key, value| key.to_s =~ /^prop/}`

Comment: Still getting the same output `params.to_h.select{|key, value| key.to_s =~ /^prop/}
=> {}`

Comment: `params.to_a
=> [["utf8", "✓"],
 ["_method", "put"],
 ["authenticity_token", "xxxxx"],
 ["userEmails", "teste@test.com,test2@test.com,test4@test.com,fasd@gmail.com"],
 ["propProperty1checkbox", "on"],
 ["propProperty1", "5"],
 ["propAnotherPropertycheckbox", "on"],
 ["propAnotherProperty", "9"],
 ["commit", "Submit"],
 ["Application", "8"],
 ["Company", "1"]]`

Comment: I have no idea then :|

Comment: No problem, I'll try work with what you gave me. Must just be a small thing! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Got it! Just had to remove.`to_h`!

`params.select{|key, value| key.to_s =~ /^prop/}` works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```rb
input(name: "props[#{pro_name}][checkbox]"...)
input(name: "props[#{pro_name}][text]"...)
```

Then, in your controller:

```rb
def method
  props = params[:props]
  props.each do |property_name, values|
    chk = values[:checkbox]
    text = values[:text]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've now edited my code to `-@all_properties.each do |prop|
    %input{:name => "prop[prop.name][checkbox]", :type => "checkbox", :id => "prop"+prop.name+"checkbox"}
    #{prop.name}
    %input{:name => "prop[prop.name][text]", :type => "text", :id => "prop"+prop.name}`

When posting the form, my params[:prop] only seems to store the data for the last input like `"prop"=>{"prop.name"=>{"checkbox"=>"on", "text"=>"2"}}`

Comment: You need text interpolation:  `:name => "prop[#{prop.name}][checkbox]"`